# Masonry effect stops working after refreshing content by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have a problem with [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library. I based my code on documentation: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html. I want to exchange elements into new ones, not append them. It was my idea but it does not work, how can I fix it?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajaxdata.htm',
    success: function (response) {
        var el = $(response);
        $('#ajax-container').masonry()
            .html(el)
            .masonry('appended', el)
            .masonry();
    }
});
```

you can find the whole code and its usage here: http://sample.silversite.pl/masonry/ or on http://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/ajd5kksz/

Comment: If you could provide a live example with the new StackOverflow CodeSnipptes I would change it to a working version.

Comment: ..OK, 
I added code on **JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/ajd5kksz/

Comment: I think I fixed it! :) 
I used **msnry.destroy()** method. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/ajd5kksz/2/ . 

I also added **imagesLoaded** .. for safety

Comment: This is quite inefficient, because Masonry has to do all it's initialization again and again.

Comment: yes I know :/ but I did not better idea..